# How to set default value for drop-down multiselect in angular 2 and ngprime

Tags: javascript, angular, drop-down-menu, primeng

I am following [PrimeNg Example](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect) .and here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bgdiVvNG94AthFtX8bSn?p=preview).How can I make some values pre selected in the drop down.

```
  <p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities"></p-multiSelect>
```

Comment: You might have a look at **[How to set default value for PrimeNG p-dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623774/how-to-set-default-value-for-primeng-p-dropdown/52290047#52290047)**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You only need to attach an **array** of values to `selectedCities` variable in order to bind this to the **model.**

In your case the **value** property is an `object` which contains many properties.

```
value:{id:1, name: 'New York', cityCode: 'NY'}
```

The solution is to `map` the array items in order to obtain the values you want.

For instance, this will preselect the fist **two** `items` from your **dropdown** element.

```
this.selectedCities = this.cities.slice(0,2).map(a => a.value));
```

If you want to preselect values from a `given` array, you should use `filter` method.

```
let arrayOfValues=['NY','IST'];
this.selectedCities = this.cities.filter(a => arrayOfValues.includes(a.value.cityCode)).map(a => a.value));
```

Comment: In PrimeNG Dropdown p-dropdown is it possible to pass value as string rather than object

Comment: For default selection, selected items is not showing in the input. If we handle selectedCities from .ts dynamically then we are not able to see how many items are selected in the input. It simply displays choose placeholder. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

The selected cities are stored in the `selectedCities` array. Since it's a two-way binding, just populate that arry, it will get reflected in the view.

```
import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/primeng';

let cities: SelectItem[] = [
    { label : "Rome"     , value : "ro" },
    { label : "London"   , value : "lo" },
    { label : "Paris"    , value : "pa" },
    { label : "New York" , value : "ny" }
]

let selectedCities: string[] = ["lo", "ny"] // This will pre-select the cities in your dropdown
```

Comment: are these selected items going to show at the top in drop down? Thanks

Comment: I don't think so. You'll have to re-order the array manually, and place selected entries first, so they show up at the top of the list.

Comment: Yeah that can always be done but expected api to handle it by default. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a good way
you can define value for each of your options.
Then define the variable selectedCities to the value you want as defult.
It will make the angular to choose that vale option on initialization.

```
let Cities: SelectItem[] = [
    { label : "Rome"     , value : "ro" },
    { label : "London"   , value : "lo" },
    { label : "Paris"    , value : "pa" },
    { label : "New York" , value : "ny" }
]

selectedCity = "ro";
```

this will set the Selected calue to defult Rome.

(*thanks to Jeremy Thille. I copied a part of my code from you.)