# Can I pre select a value in an PrimeVue Dropdown component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, primevue

**Case**: I am using `PrimeVue` in a `Vue.js` project. In this case I have a dropdown, as a component from `PrimeVue`, which uses an array of objects. The dropdown component looks like this:

```
<template #position>
    <Dropdown
        class="multiselect-fullsize"
        v-model="selectedFilter[index].pos"
        :options="filterPositions"
        optionLabel="name"
        placeholder="Position" />
    </template>
```

This dropdown component has a `:options` property, which refers to the following array:

```
filterPositions: [
    {"name": "0", "value": "0"},
    {"name": "1", "value": "1"},
    {"name": "2", "value": "2"},
    {"name": "3", "value": "3"},
    {"name": "4", "value": "4"},
    {"name": "5", "value": "5"},
    {"name": "6", "value": "6"},
    {"name": "7", "value": "7"},
    {"name": "8", "value": "8"}
  ]
```

**Question**: Is there a way to specify a pre selected item in this dropdown from `PrimeVue`?

**Edit:** According to the [documentation](https://primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/dropdown), there is no property to define a pre selected item. So maybe, if there is a solution, it could be `JavaScript` only.

Comment: I allready found a workaround for a later stage in my app, if no pre selection is possible. But this don´t answer my question.

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029399/how-to-pre-select-primeng-dropdown-values

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy I will try this soon. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried then, adding a name attribute?

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy I tried the solution and it haven´t worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is: Yes! The description in the documentation of [Dropdown | PrimeVue](https://primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/dropdown) is a bit confusing, at least for me. The problem is, that it isn´t enough to provide a `v-model` as I did with `v-model="selectedFilter[index].pos"`, I also have to define `optionValue` and in my case `optionValue="value"`, because the values in `filterPositions` have the key `value`.

Looks like, if this is set, PrimeVue´s Dropdown is able to check if the `v-model` matches the `optionValue`. If not, `v-model` would be compared to the whole `filterPositions` item. For example:

Without `optionValue="value"`:

```
{"name": "4", "value": "4"} === 4
```

With `optionValue="value"`:

```
4 === 4
```

So my Dropdown component in this case have to look like this:

```
<Dropdown
    class="multiselect-fullsize"
    v-model="selectedFilter[index].pos"
    :options="filterPositions"
    optionLabel="name"
    optionValue="value"
    placeholder="Position"
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
selectedFilter[index].pos = {"name": "4", "value": "4"}
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Answer (score -4):

just set placeholder value to pre selected value

```
<Dropdown
class="multiselect-fullsize"
v-model="selectedFilter"
:options="filterPositions"
optionLabel="name"
optionValue="value"
:placeholder="selectedFilter.value"
/>
```

Comment: Hey, that is exactly my own answer from over 2 weeks ago.

Comment: This doesn´t set a preselected value, only set a text without value